# Responsive Image Center Crop to Aspect Ratio with CSS

Tags: css, crop, aspect-ratio

I have been reading many solutions to this and tried most of them, but unfortunately I cannot get it like I want it working for all browsers.

What I basically want is to automatically crop images (from the center) to a defined aspect ratio. This should apply to "portrait" images (cropping on top and bottom) and also to landscape pictures (cropping left and right). It has to be responsive so that the images will always have the desired with (and height using the aspect ratio).

It is described well here: [Center Crop Images](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/16/centre-crop-thumbnails-with-css/) but as in that solution I do not know if the picture will be to wide or to high.

I also cannot and don't want to work with background images.

I could get it to work to crop on top and bottom but when the image is wider than the desired aspect ratio it will "crunch" the images to look distorted.

Here is one of the solutions that worked partly:

```css
/* wrapper div */
.iw-so-article-thumb {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
/* text-align: center;*/
/* ensures the image is always in the h-middle */
 border: 3px solid black;
}

/* create an aspect ratio of the wrapper */
.iw-so-article-thumb:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;
}

.iw-so-article-thumb  img {
 position: absolute;
 top: -100%;
 right: -100%;
 bottom: -100%;
 left: -100%;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
/* necessary to fill the frame/rescale the image */
}
```

This worked using "object-fit: cover" but not in IE/Edge as I found out (there pictures will be "crunched" when cropping should happen on the sides.

Like I said I tried many other solutions I found in forums/blogs but some didn't even work at all.

I suspect the cropping on the sides for wide images fails because the aspect ratio in the image wrapper is defined by the ratio of height to width, so the wrapper will take a responsive width and adapt the height (then crop by "overflow: hidden"). But when the image is wider than the aspect ratio it cannot handle this.

I am not sure if there is a pure CSS solution that works for all browsers including IE/Edge, I suspect there isn't, but I am happy to be taught otherwise.

Comment: I forgot to add, I also tried solutions using translate or translateX to shift and recenter the image, but it seemed that those do not work on the <img> tag, they did work on <div> but that did not help me.

Note that I have to work with html code created by wordpress plugins so I cannot simply change the underlying html.

Comment: maybe this can be an hint http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/BdtEj